# Does FlashPunk use GPU render like Starling?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Im interest to know if FlashPunk is a good option to make games for mobile devices.

Comment: This question I'd say is off-topic for stackoverflow as it's primarily opinion based and doesn't have a specific problem.  To strictly answer your sort-of question, no.   I remember hearing about stage3D version, but it was a separate project that I think required licensing on mobile.  I'm sure poking around the web you could easily find a good framework to use (like Starling).  Or better yet, use a web framework like Phaser or PlayCanvas and forget flash (if you're starting from scratch).

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis woaaa don't ever encourage web frameworks! Executable code for games? That sounds horrible!

Comment: @quantomworks - are you being facetious or serious?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Completely serious. I would never run a game of any kind on a web framework. Compiled code built for efficiency (AIR) is way better for that kind of thing. Especially with its ability to call on ANEs for lower services. and *especially* if the guy is making a 3D game (though flashpunk looks like a 2d service). Starling and all these awesome libs I found today is where he should be: https://github.com/romanlysenko/awesome-actionscript

Comment: @quantomworks - there are plenty of circumstances (while certainly not all) where a web framework will give satisfactory performance for a game 
- even relatively demanding ones. And like it or not web frameworks are where the industry is moving for casual games.  I think you have a misconception of the performance differences between a modern browser's 3D api's and flash. Neither are true compiled code and both can be wrapped in AIR to tap into it's functionality.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I don't know man. I know that web frameworks are definitely a thing. Though satisfactory performance can create limits. That's mainly why I stay away from a lot of industry standards. People want things done quick and not efficient. My focus here is what would be best for mobile platforms as PCs have the extra memory and processing power to make Flash vs Anything a decade long argument. And while at times you could compare AIR to a vm with libs, I still see it as better than having another process run line by line to set everything up. That goes for any ARM device.

Answer (score 0):

Flash punk is not a good option, it's a blitting engine base on the display list bitmap. You need to use Starling for GPU acceleration. It's possible to use Phaser with CocoonJS for hardware acceleration, but my experience 3 years ago was pretty bad. The support from ludei is pretty bad.

One possible option is using [Haxe flixel](http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/why-haxe/), really similar to actionscript with hardware acceleration, but probably not optimize for really big project.